# Carrierwave: Performance issue generating URL for thousands of images, due to hitting HDD for each one Edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, performance, carrierwave

I have a model where I'm using Carrierwave to let users upload their avatars. I have one version for the avatar, cropped to a square called "cropped".

```
class User
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end

class AvatarUploader < ImageUploader
  version :cropped do
    process :crop
  end
end
```

In one of my pages, where I'm listing a few thousand users, each with their avatar, the call to generate the URL for these images is taking a long time.

The problem seems to be that just by accessing to the model attribute that has the uploader mounted, Carrierwave seems to be hitting the disk to either read the file, check that it exists, or something. In other words, calling:

```
user.avatar
user.avatar.cropped
user.avatar.present?
user.avatar.anything_really
```

All of these hit the HDD.

In the worst case I found, for one of our clients that have a massive amount of data, the page renders in 10 seconds my dev machine, and 30 seconds on the server. This page render implies about 1200 calls to "user.avatar.cropped". The difference seems to be due to SSD vs HDD (or maybe overhead due to VM's, not sure). OS Disk Caching does kick in, though, since rendering the same page for a second time in the server takes 10 seconds, presumably since disk hits are cached.

If I generate the URL "manually", instead of using CarrierWave, it's back down to 10 seconds in all machines, so it's definitely Carrierwave that's causing the slowdown.

It seems like hitting the HDD shouldn't be necessary to generate the path. Is there any way to avoid this, or to work around this problem?

(NOTE: I know 10 seconds is atrocious for a page anyway, we're doing stuff to solve this, but site-wide, we have lots of pages that show tons of avatars, and we're getting a slowdown due to these HDD hits, so we'd like to improve them, without having to manually generate the URLs, since the abstraction Carrierwave provides is awesome)

UPDATE (due to comment below): We're not using eager_load. Cache_classes is off in dev, and on in production. (Again, dev is fast, prod is slow, but I don't think it's related to cache_classes)

Comment: Is there any chance `config.eager_load` is off? Or you're testing this with `config.eager_load` off? `cache_classes`? I'd expect to see this behavior if we aren't in production mode.

Comment: Our codebase doesn't say "eager_load" at all, so I'm guessing it's off, both in dev and in prod. Cache_classes is false in dev, and true in production, as you'd expect.
To clarify, this works slowly in production, and fast in dev, but I believe it's the SSD drive. eager_load doesn't seem to have an effect of whether CarrierWave hits the disk for each mounted file, does it?

Comment: For others finding this, we're also discussing this [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1219).

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue with Carrierwave and S3.

Here is my scenario, I have an API responsible of uploading avatars into S3, by default a user has an avatar that is stored in the assets folder of my API. If 10 users have a default avatar they all use the same image in order to avoir to uploads a bunch of default avatar to S3.

I have created a custom method that essentially checks if an avatar has been uploaded or not. If an avatar has been uploaded we build manually the S3 path to the avatar depending on the size. Otherwise we just return the default avatar path which is stored locally in our assets folder.

This works for a public amazon s3 bucket, I'm not sure what would happen with a private bucket or how to generate the expire parameters, but since you're using the file storage system it shouldn't be a problem.

```
module Illustrable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  end

  def avatar_img(size)
    if self.avatar?
      "http://s3.amazonaws.com/#{ ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'] }/uploads/user/avatar/#{ self.id.to_s }/#{ size }_#{ self.avatar_identifier }"
    else
      ENV['DOMAIN_NAME'] + ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path(["#{ size }_default_avatar.png"].compact.join('_'))
    end
  end

end
```

This instruction was the key for generating the name of the file and not hitting S3 to get the img path back.

```
self.avatar_identifier
```

I had a time response of 2seconds before, now I'm at 300-500ms

Hope this helps!